# Finding the Least nonnegative residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to find the least nonnegative residue of 66^75 mod 19. I know to begin by 66=9 mod 19. The following steps are what I have done next but I think I may have gotten myself into a bad spot:
66^2=9^2=5 mod 19; 66^4=5^2=6 (mod 19); 66^8=6^2=-2 (mod 19); 66^72=(-2)^9=1 (mod 19); 66^72 = 1 mod 19

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit nosy, but why have you posted 3 "finding the least nonnegative residue" questions within an hour? Were you not able to apply what you learned beforehand (in the other two questions and elsewhere) to this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Where you have left of, $\displaystyle66^{75}\equiv66^3\pmod{19}$

or as $19$ is prime and as $\displaystyle(19,66)=1,66^{19-1}\equiv1\pmod{19}\implies 66^{72}=(66^{18})^4\equiv1^4$

As$\displaystyle66\equiv9\pmod{19}, 66^3\equiv9^3=729\equiv7\pmod{19}$